# <g> element inside of a .svg doesn't scale up on :hover (css)

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm new to coding and have some issues I'm unable to resolve and hope you can help me.
The thing is: I've exported a svg-file out of Visio drawing and now I'm trying to scale an element inside this svg. 
I've used the `transform: scale(2) !important` command on hover inside the css but the element (#shape72-136 - which is the top left rectangle) is kind of vibrating instead of scaling up. Also it doesn't change to desired color.

Hope you can help me out.

```
.st1 {fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.75}
    .st2 {fill:#00b050;font-family:Calibri;font-size:1.00001em}
    .st3 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#00b050;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:1}
    .st4 {fill:none;fill-rule:evenodd;font-size:12px;overflow:visible;stroke-linecap:square;stroke-miterlimit:3}

#shape72-136:hover {fill:blue !important; width: 400px; height: 100px; transform: scale(2) !important; animation-name: example; animation-duration: 4s; animation-iteration-count: infinite;}
@keyframes example {
0% {
filter: brightness(1);
filter: contrast(1);

}
50% {
filter: brightness(2);
filter: contrast(0.1);

}
100% {
filter: brightness(1);
filter: contrast(1);

 }
}
```

You can fiddle the code:
https://jsfiddle.net/pickle/kcuntLLz/

Comment: Dear Robert, thank you for the fast reply! I've kicked out a lot of code.

Comment: It works without the inline `transform="translate(48.5326,-103.539)"` statement. But is it possible to keep position of the shape and still scale up?

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, move the static transform onto the rect element and then specify transform-origin and transform-box to ensure that the scaling works from the rect centre.

```css
.st1 {fill:none;stroke:none;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:0.75}
  .st2 {fill:#00b050;font-family:Calibri;font-size:1.00001em}
  .st3 {fill:#ffffff;stroke:#00b050;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-width:1}
  .st4 {fill:none;
    fill-rule:evenodd;
    font-size:12px;
    overflow:visible;
    stroke-linecap:square;
    stroke-miterlimit:3}
    
#shape73-138:hover {
  fill: blue !important; 
  transform: scale(1.5); 
  /*animation-name: example;*/
  animation-duration: 4s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}
  
#shape73-138 {
  transform-origin: center center;
  transform-box: fill-box;
}

@keyframes example {
  0% {
    filter: brightness(1);
    filter: contrast(1);
 
  }
  50% {
    filter: brightness(2);
    filter: contrast(0.1);
 
  }
  100% {
    filter: brightness(1);
    filter: contrast(1);
 
  }
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" width="9.90261in" height="2.57908in" viewBox="0 0 712.988 185.694" xml:space="preserve" color-interpolation-filters="sRGB" class="st4">
    
    <g>
        <g id="shape73-138">
            <title>Rechteck.69</title>
            <rect transform="translate(48.5326,-103.539)" x="0" y="143.174" width="20.1861" height="42.5197" class="st3"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, Robert. I'll test it!